# Is there any relation between two pseudofunctors associated to two different cleavages of the same fibered category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, stacks, descent, fibered-categories

It is well known that given a Fibered category $P_F: E \rightarrow C$ with a *cleavage* $K$ we can construct a pseudofunctor $F_K: C^{op} \rightarrow Cat$. Now if one chooses a **different cleavage** $L$ but consider the **same fibered category** $P_F$ then how do $F_K$ and $F_L$ are related? (Note here $F_L$ is the pseudofunctor associated to the fibered category $P_F$ with the  cleavage $L$).

Are they equivalent as objects in the 2 category of pseudofunctors over the category $C$?

I would be grateful if someone can refer any literature in this direction.

Thank you.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Let $f: v \rightarrow u$ be a morphism in $C$  $\eta$ be an object in  the fibre over $u$ . Let $\zeta_K$  and $\zeta_L$ be two corresponding Pull-Backs of $\eta_K$ and $\eta_L$ corresponding to the cleavage $K$ and $L$ respectively. Then from the definition of Cartesian Arrow there exists a unique isomorphism between $\zeta_K$ and $\zeta_L$. (Continued in the next comment)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik    Now every element  in a cleavage is a  cartesian lift of some morphism in $C$. Hence by the definition of cleavage, for every element $\phi$ in $K$ there exists a unique element $\psi$ in $L$  such that there exists a unique isomorphism between the corresponding pullbacks. From this observation I guessed (mentioned in the question) that the corresponding pseudofunctors may be equivalent as objects in the 2 category of pseudofunctors over $C$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It's not only a one-one correspondence but the corresponding pullbacks are identified upto a unique choice of isomorphism...

Comment: Ok. Because there is a relation between the collections $K$ and $L$ (as you mentioned in your previous comment), you are expecting some relation between the associated constructions $F_K,F_L:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Cat}$. Fair enough..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes exactly.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik As you wish.(I personally don't have any problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different cleavages produce isomorphic pseudofunctors.

This follows immediately from Theorem 8.3.1
in Borceux's Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2.

Specifically, part (1) of this theorem states
that for any pseudofunctors P and Q we have an isomorphism
of categories PsFun(P,Q)→Cart(φ(P),φ(Q)).

Now if P and Q are two pseudofunctors produced using two different
choices of a cleavage, then the Grothendieck fibrations φ(P) and φ(Q) are canonically isomorphic
and this isomorphism lifts to a canonical isomorphism between P and Q.

Comment: Thank You Sir very much  for the answer and the reference.

Comment: Sir, though it's been a long time since I asked the question, but I  want to clarify something here. Say, we consider category valued presheaves  $F,F': C^{\rm{op}} \rightarrow \rm{Cat}$ arising from two choices of split cleavages $K$ and $K'$ of some fibered category $\pi : E \rightarrow C$. Then will $F$ and $F'$ be naturally isomorphic as functors in the usual sense? Somehow, I am not able to produce the canonical isomorphism. [What I could only show is that $F(x)=F'(x)$ for all $x \in \rm{obj}(C)$ and $F(\gamma)$ is naturally isomorphic to $F'(\gamma)$ for all $\gamma \in \rm{Mor}(C)$ ].

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri: The two functors will be _pseudonaturally_ isomorphic.  The naturality square will not commute strictly, but rather only up to an isomorphism, and the isomorphism itself satisfies certain coherence conditions.  This isomorphism is constructed using both cleavages.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point!